# Cannot print out variables in Xcode 7

Tags: xcode

I would normally use the debug console to print out various variables at runtime to get additional information. Something along the lines of:

```
po self.objectName.objectProperty
```

Which has in the past always worked for me.

However. since updating to the latest Xcode version when I do the same command - this is what I get back:

> lldb) po self.objectName.objectProperty
>   error: member reference type 'ObjectClass *' is a pointer; did you mean to use '->'?
>   error: incomplete definition of type 'ObjectClass'
>   note: forward declaration of 'ObjectClass'
>   error: 2 errors parsing expression

This, `po self.objectName` will work just fine though.

Why is this happening?

**Edit - another example**

```
 -(void)someFunction {        
        MyObject *objectName = [[MyObject alloc] init];
       objectName.property = @"Property"; 
     //Set break point here   
    }
```

In the above example, I would do this in the console:

```
po objectName.property
```

And receive the same error message.

Comment: Where are you in the code when you issue this command?  Show the declaration of `self.objectName`.

Comment: Declaration of the object is within scope. Even if I am in a function, which has a local object; I would get the same error. Can access the object, but not its properties.

Comment: I don't know what that means.  If `objectName` were of type `id` I would have thought you would get this kind of error.

Comment: As I say, I have been able to access properties like this no problem before. Its a new issue for me. I've updated my question with a new example.